# PHPStorm вставка <?php ?> тега в html

Tags: phpstorm

Как в **PHPStorm6** реализовать вставку в html **php тега** `<?php ?>`при вводе: **php** клавиша [tab] ? Сейчас выдает `<php></php>`.

Нужно:

`<div>
    <?php  ?>
</div>`

Получаю:

`<div>
    <php></php>
</div>`

Comment: Ваше сообщение не содержит вопроса. Поясните, пожалуйста, в чём возникла проблема?

Comment: Можно ли PHPStorm6 вставить в html '<?php ?>' теги по команде php(tab), как в Sublime Text? Сейчас выдает '<php></php>'

Comment: Да можно, Live Templates в настройках смотрите.

Comment: @Godzo Внесите ваш комментарий в формулировку вопроса. В таком случае, его переоткроют гораздо быстрее.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Выберите пункт меню
`File -> Settings -> -- IDE Settings -- -> Live Templates -> Add`

Далее скриншоты из 8-ой версии, но суть абсолютно та же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполните данные следующим образом:

> Abbreviation: php
>   Template Text: `<?php $END$ ?>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом определите контекст (HTML):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Закройте окно и сохраните изменения. Вот и все.

Дополнительно:
[Live Templates (Snippets) in PhpStorm - PhpStorm Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LXJfYvq8z8)

Составлено на основе вопроса на SO:
[Phpstorm zen coding: insert  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165203/phpstorm-zen-coding-insert-php-tag)

Comment: Огонь! Спасибо за ответ. Для 10ки работает тоже, мало того настроил себе при вводе: **pr** клавиша [tab] => print_r();